# PHP decode literal string

Tags: php, string, hex, bin

in php for decode a hex string we use hex2bin() function
for example "test" in hex is : "74657374"

Now i want to add \x format to them , Like this :  `\x74\x65\x73\x74`

How do i can decode this ?

I wrote a function that removes \x from this string with 'preg_replace' or 'str_replace'
But , Does it has a function in php it self for this ?

I searched but i can't find any good result...

How can i do this in php ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to decode/convert the string "\x74\x65\x73\x74" - The PHP interpreter will do it for you using the escape sequence ("\x")

```
<?php

echo "\x74\x65\x73\x74"; // "test"

?>
```